# UI Bootstrap vs Angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-material

Currently my angular (v1) app exensively uses UI Bootstrap directives.
I would like to switch to Angular Material, but I'm worried about its weight (just the minified css is about 400kB, with some js modules we're talking about MBs).

Another major point: I don't get the `flex` choice for the grid layout, is not well supported and you will end to reduce the already bad old browser compatibility (since is an angular app).

I'm here mostly to take advices.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the entire library. You can either install individual components from NPM or use "tree shaking" tools to determine which components are being used and only include them in your output build/bundle. The latter assumes you're using some kind of build tool like Webpack.

Flexbox has been around for years and is well supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

If you really need IE10 support, you can use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to append vendor prefixes and "2012" flexbox syntax to your stylesheets. Again, this works best if you're using some kind of build tool.

Comment: what about performances issues?
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8329

I simply don't want to risk to make a huge (not requested) extra work to ends with more troubles..

Comment: There are no noticable performance issues with flexbox. The only thing that could cause performance issues is a polyfill but Autoprefixer is not a polyfill, it's a pre-processor. It just adds in additional vendor prefixes that IE10 might need.

Comment: by performance issues I meant overall, not only flex related. Anyway thanks for the answers. Just a couple more: - Do you know a way to accomplish Parent to child transition in angular material?https://material.google.com/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#navigational-transitions-parent-to-child
- maybe there are some blank templates to get started with my layout (not admin dashboard, something more like Google Trends layout)?

Comment: It depends on which browsers and which versions. The best way to find out is to do your own benchmarks. All modern browsers comes with profiling tools.